# Android MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648) in Android 5.0 and later

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and I am developing a music app.

When I play streamed audio from URL, it's working fine in Android API lower than 21, but in Lollipop version it's not playing and showing

> MediaPlayer(4651): error (1, -2147483648)

Code:

```
public void playSong()
{
    player.reset();
    player.setVolume(100,100);
    try
    {
        player.setDataSource(songURL);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    player.prepareAsync();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    //start playback
    player.start();
}
```